# Is there any way to play audio in the phonecall with dialogflow-CX only?

Tags: python, dialogflow-cx

So I'm trying to stream this audio URL, and I tried is multiple ways but I cant get ti to play over a phone call.

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle():
    req = request.get_json(force=True)
    print(f"Request data: {req}")  # Print the request data

    user_text = req.get('transcript')
    tag = req["fulfillmentInfo"]["tag"]

    print(f"User text: {user_text}, Tag: {tag}")  # Print the user text and action

    response = ""  # Initialize response

    if tag == 'dialogflowRES':
        if user_text is not None:
            response = "Hello this is an example"
        else:
            response = ""
    
    print(f"Response: {response}")  # Print the response

    if "Bye" in response:        
        return jsonify({
            'fulfillment_response': {
                'messages': [{
                    'text': {
                        'text': [response]
                    }
                }]
            },
            'end_interaction': True
        })
    else:
        # Replace 'audio_public_url' with the public URL of your audio file
        audio_public_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/twiliobucket/output.wav'
        return jsonify({
            'fulfillment_response': {
                'messages': [{
                    'payload': {
                        'telephonySynthesizeSpeech': {
                            'text': response,
                            'ssml': f'<speak><audio src="{audio_public_url}"/></speak>'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
```

I also tried a different syntax but it still didn't work.

```
        return jsonify({
            'fulfillment_response': {
                'messages': [{
                    'payload': {
                        'audio': {
                            'uri': audio_public_url,
                            'config': {
                                'audioEncoding': 'AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16',
                                'sampleRateHertz': 8000
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        })
```

I'm using Flask in this case, and I just want to play this prerecorded audio file.

Comment: Hi Extraordinary, Does these 2 [Link1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/detect-intent-audio) and [Link2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/phone-gateway) will help you ?

Comment: @ArpitaShrivastava no unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/Fulfillment#ResponseMessage), you should use the `playAudio` property:

```py
{
    "fulfillment_response": {
        "messages": [{"payload": {"playAudio": {"audioUri": audio_public_url}}}]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, see the problem is that its still a message but it has audio embedded into it. What I'm looking for is a way to play the sound over the phone with the one-tap telephony integration of dialogflow.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "it's still a message".  I would expect the telephony integration to fetch the URI and play the audio file. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes I have indeed tried, It doesn't not play the audio